# How do I add lines (read from a .txt) separated by AN ENTER KEY (in .txt) into separate elements of string arrayList?

Tags: java, text, arraylist, filereader

I'm reading .txt file into my program and am adding lines of the .txt into a String arrayList. How do I add lines DELINEATED BY AN ENTER KEY (in .txt) into separate elements of the arrayList? Right now if I had the following written in text:

> this is a test
>
> test
>
> test test

It would output:

> **this is a testtesttest    test**

What I want it to do is read things on a per line basis, and put it into different elements of the stringArrayList. So I want *"this is a test"* to be an element, and *"test"*, and then finally *"test test"*.

My code is really ugly, but right now all I want to do is get it to work for my purpose. My first purpose is getting to read a .txt by line. My second purpose is going to be parsing an element for a particular substring (a URL), connecting that URL to the internet, and then comparing a part of that page source of the webpage (parsing for a particular keyword) to the line ABOVE the substring I desire. But that's a question for another time :^)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "test.txt";
        List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;

        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                
                System.out.println(line);
                listA.add(line);
                //*** THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS ***\\ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

            }   

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open da file ofheee hah. '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                  
            // Or we could just do this: 
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("array FOr loop thingy incoming:");
        System.out.println();


        for (int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print((listA.get(i)).toString());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You're using `System.out.print` with each element - that *doesn't* print a line break. Try `println` instead. (There are clearer ways to write this code, admittedly.)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use `println` instead of print:

```
System.out.println((listA.get(i)).toString());
```

Alternatively, you can add the line break character `\n`

Comment: Embarrassingly simple solution. Thanks luanjot.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working so far. If you just want to see what elements are in `listA`, just print it out:

```
System.out.println(listA);
```

Output:

```
[this is a test, , test, , test test, ]
```

Note that the extra lines in your input file are also being stored in `listA`. I'm not sure if that's the behavior you want.